# I want to find the value of an equation with rounding down

Tags: python, algorithm, integer

```
x=[340,1123,3423,...] # x has random integers.
for i in x:
   a= ~~~ that satisfied with int((x+a)*0.2)= int(x*0.2)+1
```

In this case, what is the way to calculate this a?

Assume that `int()` is a rounding function I want to make an expression like

> a= ~~~

But I can't come up with an idea.

Comment: `a` will have integer solutions only? Add examples to the problem as well

Comment: are you trying to create a list that only holds the integers from x that satisfy the expression?

Comment: I highly recommend adding examples and even what do you want to round off exactly. Please make it bit more clear!

Comment: Thinking about it, I found that the value of a is a range, not just an integer. The goal is to find the smallest integer in a range.

Comment: @ddd add this information to the question then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a = 5` should work for all `x`:

multiply both sides of the equation with `5` and you get `round(x+a) - round(x) = 5`. if `x` is an integer you get `a=5`. and due to the rounding `a = 6` and others should work.